# how to avoid usage of static fields in activity and fragment

Tags: android, architecture, static, refactoring, public

I have a poroject that was developed by other developer. There are a lot of public static fields, arrays and etc. And this public static fields are being called like from everywhere(every class). It causes a lot of crashes. I need some architectural advice. Anyway, im gonna need to refactor all this code. How can i avoid using static fields? I know how to do it using interface, espessially when dealing with activity-fragment communication. Maybe you can suggest some libraries for this purposes?

Comment: without any piece of code, it's extremely hard to help you. The main rule is "do not use static fields unless it's really need or it's a constant"... but how to replace a static field depends of the usage of it. Communication between Activities can be done via Intent's bundle, but preferences storage should be done via SharedPreferences...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Dagger 2](http://square.github.io/dagger/) for dependency injection.

Introduction from [http://code.tutsplus.com/](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-on-android--cms-23345), also this is a very good tutorial for using dagger.

> When you have an object that needs or depends on another object to do its work, you have a dependency. Dependencies can be solved by letting the dependent object create the dependency or asking a factory object to make one. In the context of dependency injection, however, the dependencies are supplied to the class that needs the dependency to avoid the need for the class itself to create them. This way you create software that is loosely coupled and highly maintainable.

Also check [this tutorial](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/04/11/tasting-dagger-2-on-android/) too for better understanding.

Comment: thanks. i heard some negative feedbacks about dagger. is it already working fine? Can it be used on commercial products?

Comment: It's working fine yes, we use it in many big commercial projects.